# Prevent mouse scroll event not to collapse dropdown panel when using Prime autocomplete

Tags: angular, autocomplete, primeng

I am using a PrimeNG `p-autocomplete` to search input field.

But if users scroll up/down, the dropdown panel disappears. How can I make dropdown panel collapse(disappear) only if users explicitly click outside of dropdown panel?

Official document example works well as I want to intend but mine doesn't.
https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/autocomplete

Also, there is a scroll event on document. It works well after I remove the scroll event. Is this a right solution? Otherwise, what should I do?

[image]

[image]

```
  <p-autoComplete
          styleClss="autoComplete-override"
          formControlName="search"
          field="title"
          placeholder="QQQ, ARKK"
          [suggestions]="suggestedEtfs"
          (onSelect)="autoCompleteSelect($event)"
        ></p-autoComplete>
```

```
  public autoCompleteSelect(value) {

    this.goToStockList(value.symbol);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this issue after updating Angular 10 to Angular 11.